# Why is MySQL retrieving a DATE data type with timezone conversion added?

Tags: mysql, node.js, date

A string in format 'YYYY-MM-DD' is being stored to a DATE field in MySQL. When retrieving the table with SELECT, it returns the wrong date always a day before the actual stored date, for example, as 'YYYY-MM-DDT21:00:00.000Z' UTC time,
when it should be returning the basic date without timezones since the DATE data type does not store any time information i.e. 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
Why is it returning the date with timezone information and how can it be removed?

Tabel configuation for date field: `'movedate' date DEFAULT NULL`. Engine is InnoDB and `CHARSET=latin1`.

Comment: Can you add table configuration? update your question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE 'table_name'` output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mysql module (which I presume you're using!), states that the conversion to JavaScript date objects uses the timezone property of the connection configuration, the details are here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-options

In any case, if the Dates are stored in UTC, we can specify that they are retrieved as such using the timezone property of the connection configuration, like so:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
    
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "****",
    database: 'test_db',
    timezone: 'Z'
});

db.query("SELECT * from dates", (err, result) => { 
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", err);
    } else { 
        console.log("Results:", result);
    }
})
```

Comment: This seems to work and keep the original date and fixes the issue of returning the date one day before the actual stored data (edited question), but it still leaves the T00:00:00.000Z formatting to the end of the string. Although it's not an big issue anymore to remove the last portion.

Comment: My concern is that because the database contains other date and timestamp data types with time information how will adding the timezone 'Z' to config affect the rest of those?

Comment: That's a legitimate concern, since you make the change at a configuration level, rather than at the query level. It would be worth testing to determine the impact of this change. One _could_ create a separate connection for this query, to avoid impacting the other queries.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by saving the date into a variable and from there just using JavaScript's date's get methods, e.g. getMonth(). The get methods seem to change the date back into the original date.

So if the stored date in the database was `2007-02-01`, the date retrieved was `2007-01-31T22:00:00.000Z`, then using the date methods, the result is `2007-02-01`.

Because the date retrieved from DB is a valid date object, the JavaScript get methods will get each day/month/year seperately.